# How to Extract different subset of data in text file and pass each subset into another text file?

Tags: python-3.x, text-processing

I have few text files, and I need to subset the subheading data and content of that subheading data and pass to another file.

The text file looks like this

```
Notes 

1. content

2. here also there will be some content till n lines

rule Note 

1. n line content (a) for every section

Add Notes

(a) some content

other Note

1. the rest of file
```

```
***Code***
    with open(file,encoding='utf8') as in_file: 
        s = in_file.read() 

        for i, char in enumerate(s): 
            if s[i:i+5] == 'Notes': 
                break      

        for j in range(i,0,-1): 
            if s[j] == '\n': 
                break
        rest_of_file = s[j+1:]
```

The above code extract the data from text file from Notes. 
so my expected output some thing looks like this in 1st iteration and need to pass to another file

```
Notes 

1. content

2. here also there will be some content till n lines
```

2nd iteration

```
rule Note 

1. n line content (a) for every section
```

3rd iteration

```
Add Notes

(a) some content
```

final iteration

```
other Note

1. the rest of file
```

***Note:*** This is one file which has all subheadings with patter but it may not be same for all the text files. some files may miss Notes ,some may miss rule Note and Add Notes,some files may have directly other note like that it may happen

only common pattern i found here is Note

any approach is fine  can any one help with this pls...
ready to work with beautiful soup also

Comment: Which _other file_ do you _need to pass_ the notes to? And what's the point of copying all the notes to one other file? (This is equivalent to deleting all lines above `Notes`.)

Comment: I have 19 text files like this. each file may not have every subheading of Note. I have a dependency here i need to make a dictionary for this to differentiate between each subheading note. if i pass into one more file it will be easy to differentiate using regex if line 1 matches i will pass content  in particular key

Comment: You did neither answer my questions, nor point out any misunderstanding on my side. Also, what do you mean by _a dictionary_ with respect to _another file_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach for this is

1. passed everything into list
2. if Note appears in items get index of item into list
3. based on indexes list separate it with different sections

sample code is here:

[how to get subset of list from index of list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949247/how-to-get-subset-of-list-from-index-of-list-in-python)