# how to get subset of list from index of list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-processing

I had a list of strings, I need to subset from the list based on their indexes list  in generic manner

```
indx=[0,5,7] # index list

a = ['a', 'b', 3, 4, 'd', 6, 7, 8]
```

I need to get subsets in generic manner in first iteration:

```
a[0:5]
```

2nd iteration:

```
a[5:7]
```

3rd iteration:

```
a[7:]
```

The code I have tried:

```
for i in indx:
    if len(indx)==i:
        print(a[i:])
    else:
        print(a[i:i+1])
```

Expected output:

```
a[0:5]=='a', 'b', 3, 4, 'd'
a[5:7]=6, 7
a[7:]=8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
indx.append(len(a))
print(*[a[i:j] for i,j in zip(indx, indx[1:])], sep='\n')
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
['a', 'b', 3, 4, 'd']
[6, 7]
[8]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a comprehension:

```
>>> [a[x:y] for x,y in zip(indx,[*indx[1:], None])]
[['a', 'b', 3, 4, 'd'], [6, 7], [8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
results = [a[indx[i]:indx[i+1]] for i in range(len(indx)-1)]
```

Will return a list containing the 3 lists you want.

Answer (score 0):

You were right in thinking of iterating through two items at once, but the issue is that `for i in lst` does not use indexes, and will fail.

One way to iterate and take two items is by using zip.

```
indx=[0,5,7] # index list

a = ['a', 'b', 3, 4, 'd', 6, 7, 8]

if indx[0] != 0:
    indx = [0] + indx #fixes left indexing in case 0 is not present
if indx[-1] != len(a):
    indx += [len(a)] #fixes right indexing to make sure you get all values from the list.

print(indx) #[0, 5, 7, 8]
for left, right in zip(indx, indx[1:]):
    print(a[left: right])
#Output:
['a', 'b', 3, 4, 'd']
[6, 7]
[8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
for i in range(len(indx)):
try:
    print("a[%s:%s] ==" % (indx[i], indx[i + 1]) + " ", end=" ")
    print(a[indx[i]:indx[i + 1]])
except IndexError:
    print("a[%s:] ==" % (indx[i]) + " ", end=" ")
    print(a[indx[i]:])
```

Output:

```
a[0:5] ==  ['a', 'b', 3, 4, 'd']
a[5:7] ==  [6, 7]
a[7:] ==  [8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `slice` type to convert your index list into list slices. As others have already posted, use `zip` to create the start-finish pairs:

```
>>> print(list(zip(indx, indx[1:]+[None])))
[(0, 5), (5, 7), (7, None)]
```

We use these pairs to define slices:

```
>>> slices = [slice(a, b) for a, b in zip(indx, indx[1:]+[None])]
```

Then use the slice object just like you would an integer index, but the slice will select the list substring as defined in the slice start-finish pair:

```
>>> for slc in slices:
...     print(a[slc])
```

Gives:

```
['a', 'b', 3, 4, 'd']
[6, 7]
[8]
```